# Context menu depending on Listbox item type

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, contextmenu, converters

Is it good idea to select `ContextMenu` of `ListBox` item through `Converter` or is there some better way to do it?

*Just to be clear I will describe my situation:*

I have a Listbox control. As a **ItemsSource** of this Lisbox is `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`

I've set ContextMenu of ItemContainerStyle of the Listbox to look like this :

```
<Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource contextMenuConverter}}"/ >
```

In *ContextMenuConverter* I check some properties of MyClass class and select `ContextMenu` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, no, thats actually pretty good.

Another option would be to bind the `SelectedItem` to your `ViewModel`, bind the `ContextMenu` property to the same, and return a new `ContextMenu` whenever the `SelectedItem` is changed, based on the `SelectedItem`.

But, frankly, I like your solution more. Its cleaner.